# _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!notebook.!frame2.!button" and I need some general feedback :)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming and this is my first "big" project.

This program is supposed to be stats viewer, that is working with an api.
My problem was, that I tried to implement a Reset and a Refresh button, and it didn't work.

But first of all, here is the code I got so far (without Refresh/Reset button), and I would really appreciate some general feedback:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import requests
from time import gmtime
import time
import math
import pandas
import json


def is_key_valid():
    key = entry_one_tab_one.get()
    api_data_key =  requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/key?key=" + key).json()
    key_valid = api_data_key["success"]
    if(key_valid == 1):
        label_one_tab_one.config(fg="green2")
        textvar1.set("API key is valid")
        label_one_tab_parrent.config(text="API key is valid", fg="green2")

    else:
        label_one_tab_one.config(fg="red2")
        textvar1.set("API key is invalid")
        label_one_tab_parrent.config(text="API key is invalid", fg="red2")

    requests_last_min = api_data_key["record"]["queriesInPastMin"]
    label_two_tab_parrent.config(text= str(requests_last_min) + " Requests/last min." )

    if requests_last_min < 48 :
        label_two_tab_parrent.config(fg="green2")
    elif requests_last_min < 84 :
        label_two_tab_parrent.config(fg="yellow")
    else:
        label_two_tab_parrent.config(fg="red2")


def general_stats():

    button_one_tab_two.place_forget()
    entry_one_tab_two.place_forget()


    key = entry_one_tab_one.get()
    player = entry_one_tab_two.get()
    api_data_player = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=" + key + "&name=" + player).json()
    player_last_logout = api_data_player["player"]["lastLogout"]
    player_last_logout_readable_time = pandas.to_datetime(player_last_logout, unit="ms")



    player_first_join = api_data_player["player"]["firstLogin"]
    current_time = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    time_on_hypixel_unix = current_time - player_first_join
    time_on_hypixel_readable = (time_on_hypixel_unix / 31556952000)
    time_on_hypixel_readable_rounded = round(time_on_hypixel_readable, 1)




    if "rank" in api_data_player["player"] and api_data_player["player"]["rank"] != "NORMAL":
        api_data_player = api_data_player["player"]["rank"]
    elif "newPackageRank" in api_data_player["player"]:
        api_data_player = api_data_player["player"]["newPackageRank"]
    elif "packageRank" in api_data_player["player"]:
        api_data_player = api_data_player["player"]["packageRank"]
    else:
        api_data_player = "Non"


    label_one_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="Name: " + player)
    label_one_tab_two.place(x=0, y=30)


    label_two_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text=api_data_player)
    label_two_tab_two.place(x=40, y=50)

    label_three_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="Rank: ")
    label_three_tab_two.place(x=0, y=50)

    if api_data_player in ("VIP", "VIP_PLUS"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="green2")
    elif api_data_player in ("MVP", "MVP_PLUS"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="cyan2")
    elif api_data_player in ("Non"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="grey80")
    elif api_data_player in ("HELPER"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="blue2")
    elif api_data_player in ("MODERATOR"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="green3")
    elif api_data_player in ("YOUTUBER", "ADMIN", "OWNER"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="red2")


    api_data_mojang = requests.get("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + player).json()
    player_uuid = api_data_mojang["id"]
    api_data_status = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/status?key=" + key + "&uuid=" + player_uuid).json()
    print("https://api.hypixel.net/status?key=" + key + "&uuid=" + player_uuid)


    label_four_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="Online: ")
    label_four_tab_two.place(x=0, y=70)

    label_four_point_one_tab_two = Label(tab_two)
    label_four_point_one_tab_two.place(x=45, y=70)

    label_five_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="↳ ")
    label_five_tab_two.place(x=50, y=85)

    label_six_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="↳ ")
    label_six_tab_two.place(x=50, y=100)

    label_seven_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="↳ ")
    label_seven_tab_two.place(x=50, y=115)



    player_online = api_data_status["session"]["online"]


    if player_online == 1 and "map" in api_data_status["session"]:
        label_four_point_one_tab_two.config(fg="green2", text=str(player_online))

        player_game_type = api_data_status["session"]["gameType"]
        label_five_tab_two.config(text="↳ " + player_game_type)

        player_game_type_mode = api_data_status["session"]["mode"]
        label_six_tab_two.config(text="↳ " + player_game_type_mode)

        player_game_map = api_data_status["session"]["map"]
        label_seven_tab_two.config(text="↳ " + player_game_map)

        ypos = 135
    elif player_online == 1 and not "map" in api_data_status["session"]:
        label_four_point_one_tab_two.config(fg="green2", text=str(player_online))

        player_game_type = api_data_status["session"]["gameType"]
        label_five_tab_two.config(text="↳ " + player_game_type)

        player_game_type_mode = api_data_status["session"]["mode"]
        label_six_tab_two.config(text="↳ " + player_game_type_mode)

        label_seven_tab_two.place_forget()

        ypos = 120
    else:
        label_four_point_one_tab_two.config(fg="red2", text=str(player_online) + "   |   last logout: " + str(player_last_logout_readable_time) + "  GMT")

        label_five_tab_two.place_forget()
        label_six_tab_two.place_forget()
        label_seven_tab_two.place_forget()

        ypos = 90

    label_nine_tab_two= Label(tab_two, text= "On Hypixel for " + str(time_on_hypixel_readable_rounded) + " Years")
    label_nine_tab_two.place(x= 0,y= ypos)




root = Tk()


root.title("Hypixel API project")
root.geometry("520x500")


tab_parrent = ttk.Notebook(root)


tab_one = ttk.Frame(tab_parrent)
tab_two = ttk.Frame(tab_parrent)

tab_parrent.add(tab_one, text="Settings")
tab_parrent.add(tab_two, text="General player information")


tab_parrent.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

#-------------------------------------------------Main Tab-------------------------------------------------#

label_one_tab_parrent = Label(tab_parrent, text="no API")
label_one_tab_parrent.place(x=403, y=25)

requests_last_min = "?"

label_two_tab_parrent = Label(tab_parrent, text= " ")
label_two_tab_parrent.place(x=403, y=43)


#-------------------------------------------------Settings-------------------------------------------------#

entry_one_tab_one = Entry(tab_one)
entry_one_tab_one.place(x=0, y=30)

button_one_tab_one = Button(tab_one, text="Set API key", command = is_key_valid)
button_one_tab_one.place(x=130, y=27)

textvar1 = StringVar()
textvar1.set("API key unknown")


label_one_tab_one = Label(tab_one, textvariable=textvar1, fg= "black")
label_one_tab_one.place(x=0, y=50)

#-------------------------------------------------General player information-------------------------------------------------#



entry_one_tab_two = Entry(tab_two)
entry_one_tab_two.place(x=0, y=30)

button_one_tab_two = Button(tab_two, text="Search", command=general_stats)
button_one_tab_two.place(x=130, y=27)

tab_parrent.mainloop()
```

But onto to the actuall problem I had, I tried to implement a reset and refresh button(with this code):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import requests
from time import gmtime
import time
import math
import pandas



def is_key_valid():
    key = entry_one_tab_one.get()
    api_data_key =  requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/key?key=" + key).json()
    key_valid = api_data_key["success"]
    if(key_valid == 1):
        label_one_tab_one.config(fg="green2")
        textvar1.set("API key is valid")
        label_one_tab_parrent.config(text="API key is valid", fg="green2")

    else:
        label_one_tab_one.config(fg="red2")
        textvar1.set("API key is invalid")
        label_one_tab_parrent.config(text="API key is invalid", fg="red2")

    requests_last_min = api_data_key["record"]["queriesInPastMin"]
    label_two_tab_parrent.config(text= str(requests_last_min) + " Requests/last min." )

    if requests_last_min < 48 :
        label_two_tab_parrent.config(fg="green2")
    elif requests_last_min < 84 :
        label_two_tab_parrent.config(fg="yellow")
    else:
        label_two_tab_parrent.config(fg="red2")


def general_stats():

    button_one_tab_two.place_forget()
    entry_one_tab_two.place_forget()


    key = entry_one_tab_one.get()
    player = entry_one_tab_two.get()
    api_data_player = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=" + key + "&name=" + player).json()
    player_last_logout = api_data_player["player"]["lastLogout"]
    player_last_logout_readable_time = pandas.to_datetime(player_last_logout, unit="ms")



    player_first_join = api_data_player["player"]["firstLogin"]
    current_time = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    time_on_hypixel_unix = current_time - player_first_join
    time_on_hypixel_readable = (time_on_hypixel_unix / 31556952000)
    time_on_hypixel_readable_rounded = round(time_on_hypixel_readable, 1)




    if "rank" in api_data_player["player"] and api_data_player["player"]["rank"] != "NORMAL":
        api_data_player = api_data_player["player"]["rank"]
    elif "newPackageRank" in api_data_player["player"]:
        api_data_player = api_data_player["player"]["newPackageRank"]
    elif "packageRank" in api_data_player["player"]:
        api_data_player = api_data_player["player"]["packageRank"]
    else:
        api_data_player = "Non"



    label_one_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="Name: " + player)
    label_one_tab_two.place(x=0, y=30)


    label_two_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text=api_data_player)
    label_two_tab_two.place(x=40, y=50)

    label_three_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="Rank: ")
    label_three_tab_two.place(x=0, y=50)

    if api_data_player in ("VIP", "VIP_PLUS"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="green2")
    elif api_data_player in ("MVP", "MVP_PLUS"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="cyan2")
    elif api_data_player in ("Non"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="grey80")
    elif api_data_player in ("HELPER"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="blue2")
    elif api_data_player in ("MODERATOR"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="green3")
    elif api_data_player in ("YOUTUBER", "ADMIN", "OWNER"):
        label_two_tab_two.config(fg="red2")


    api_data_mojang = requests.get("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + player).json()
    player_uuid = api_data_mojang["id"]
    api_data_status = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/status?key=" + key + "&uuid=" + player_uuid).json()


    label_four_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="Online: ")
    label_four_tab_two.place(x=0, y=70)

    label_four_point_one_tab_two = Label(tab_two)
    label_four_point_one_tab_two.place(x=45, y=70)

    label_five_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="↳ ")
    label_five_tab_two.place(x=50, y=85)

    label_six_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="↳ ")
    label_six_tab_two.place(x=50, y=100)

    label_seven_tab_two = Label(tab_two, text="↳ ")
    label_seven_tab_two.place(x=50, y=115)



    player_online = api_data_status["session"]["online"]


    if player_online == 1 and "map" in api_data_status["session"]:
        label_four_point_one_tab_two.config(fg="green2", text=str(player_online))

        player_game_type = api_data_status["session"]["gameType"]
        label_five_tab_two.config(text="↳ " + player_game_type)

        player_game_type_mode = api_data_status["session"]["mode"]
        label_six_tab_two.config(text="↳ " + player_game_type_mode)

        player_game_map = api_data_status["session"]["map"]
        label_seven_tab_two.config(text="↳ " + player_game_map)

        ypos = 135
    elif player_online == 1 and not "map" in api_data_status["session"]:
        label_four_point_one_tab_two.config(fg="green2", text=str(player_online))

        player_game_type = api_data_status["session"]["gameType"]
        label_five_tab_two.config(text="↳ " + player_game_type)

        player_game_type_mode = api_data_status["session"]["mode"]
        label_six_tab_two.config(text="↳ " + player_game_type_mode)

        label_seven_tab_two.place_forget()

        ypos = 120
    else:
        label_four_point_one_tab_two.config(fg="red2", text=str(player_online) + "   |   last logout: " + str(player_last_logout_readable_time) + "  GMT")

        label_five_tab_two.place_forget()
        label_six_tab_two.place_forget()
        label_seven_tab_two.place_forget()

        ypos = 90



    label_eight_tab_two= Label(tab_two, text= "On Hypixel for " + str(time_on_hypixel_readable_rounded) + " Years")
    label_eight_tab_two.place(x= 0,y= ypos)



def refresh():
    for widget in tab_two.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    general_stats()









def reset():
    for widget in tab_two.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
        button_two_tab_two = Button(tab_two, text="Refresh")
        button_two_tab_two.place(x=400, y=45)

        button_three_tab_two = Button(tab_two, text="Reset", command=reset)
        button_three_tab_two.place(x=450, y=45)
        entry_one_tab_two = Entry(tab_two)
        entry_one_tab_two.place(x=0, y=30)

        button_one_tab_two = Button(tab_two, text="Search", command=general_stats)
        button_one_tab_two.place(x=130, y=27)











root = Tk()





root.title("Hypixel API project")
root.geometry("520x500")




tab_parrent = ttk.Notebook(root)


tab_one = ttk.Frame(tab_parrent)
tab_two = ttk.Frame(tab_parrent)

tab_parrent.add(tab_one, text="Settings")
tab_parrent.add(tab_two, text="General player information")


tab_parrent.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

#-------------------------------------------------Main Tab-------------------------------------------------#

label_one_tab_parrent = Label(tab_parrent, text="no API")
label_one_tab_parrent.place(x=403, y=25)

requests_last_min = "?"

label_two_tab_parrent = Label(tab_parrent, text= " ")
label_two_tab_parrent.place(x=403, y=43)


#-------------------------------------------------Settings-------------------------------------------------#

entry_one_tab_one = Entry(tab_one)
entry_one_tab_one.place(x=0, y=30)

button_one_tab_one = Button(tab_one, text="Set API key", command = is_key_valid)
button_one_tab_one.place(x=130, y=27)

textvar1 = StringVar()
textvar1.set("API key unknown")


label_one_tab_one = Label(tab_one, textvariable=textvar1, fg= "black")
label_one_tab_one.place(x=0, y=50)

#-------------------------------------------------General player information-------------------------------------------------#



entry_one_tab_two = Entry(tab_two)
entry_one_tab_two.place(x=0, y=30)

button_one_tab_two = Button(tab_two, text="Search", command=general_stats)
button_one_tab_two.place(x=130, y=27)

button_two_tab_two = Button(tab_two, text="Refresh" )
button_two_tab_two.place(x=400, y=45)

button_three_tab_two = Button(tab_two, text="Reset", command=reset)
button_three_tab_two.place(x=450, y=45)




tab_one.mainloop()
```

and it  resets tab two perfectly fine, but if I try to do a search then I get this error message:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1883, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
>
> File "C:\Users\steph\Desktop\Python Projects\API test\Main.py", line 38, in general_stats
> button_one_tab_two.place_forget()
>
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 2447, in place_forget
> self.tk.call('place', 'forget', self._w)
>
> _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!notebook.!frame2.!button"

I tried some googling for the error message but I didn't find anything helpful.

And again, I am new to programming so general feedback is much appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The widgets you create inside `reset()` are all referred to via local variables, that vanish at the end of the function.  The global variables of the same names remain unchanged, and still refer to the original widgets that have now been destroyed.

Comment: thx :) and how do I fix that? any I dea? causeI dont know xD